# How do i create a custom page size using backdrop

Tags: custom

I am using backdrop with civicrm 5.65.0 and need to create a custom page size so that i can then create a mailing label for a 6"x4" label printer.

Please help. I cant find anything that tells me how to do this

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Administer - System Settings - Options Groups - Paper Size, you can add a new paper size based on the format for existing options.

Then you can go to Administer - Communications - Label Page Formats and create a label page format.